# Misalignment on the authors names

Tags: titles

I want to put an [article from a website](https://www.isoc.org/inet97/proceedings/F3/F3_1.HTM) on pdf to make it easier to read and print.

It's almost done and complet and the result look correct, but I have an issue with the alignment of the authors names as you can see here:

[image: PDF Capture]

I'm not sure what cause that shifting to the right for the first author, can you help me to solve that? here is my actual header:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{float}
\pagestyle{fancy} 
\usepackage{graphicx}

\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[L]{Characteristics of UDP Packet Loss - Effect of TCP Traffic}
\cfoot{\hfill \thepage\ sur \pageref{LastPage}}

\author{
    Hidenari, Sawashima\\ \texttt{<hidena-s@is.aist-nara.ac.jp>}\\ Nara Institute of Science and Technology\\ Japan\\~
\and
    Yoshiaki, Hori\\ \texttt{<hori@kyushu-id.ac.jp>} \\ Kyushu Institute of Design\\ Japan\\~
\and
    Hideki Sunahara\\ \texttt{<suna@wide.ad.jp>}\\ Nara Institute of Science and Technology\\ Japan
\and
    Yuji Oie\\ \texttt{<oie@itc.aist-nara.ac.jp>}\\ Nara Institute of Science and Technology\\ Japan
}

\date{}

\title{\textbf{\huge Characteristics of UDP Packet Loss \\Effect of TCP Traffic}\\~\\~\texttt{\normalsize https://www.isoc.org/inet97/proceedings/F3/F3\_1.HTM\\~}}

\begin{document}

    \maketitle

    \vspace{40pt}
    \begin{abstract}
    ...
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why is there a comma between the first and last names for the first two authors but not for the final two authors?

Comment: Mainly because... I forgot to add them, thank you for having pointing them!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It only *looks like* the first author's block is shifted to the right. What's actually going on is that the two authors in the first row are jointly centered horizontally and are typeset independently from the two authors in the next row (which are also jointly centered horizontally in the available text block)

To obtain vertical alignment across the rows, it's necessary to place the author information into nested `tabular` environments.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,fancyvrb,float}
\pagestyle{fancy} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs} % for '\addlinespace' macro

\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[L]{Characteristics of UDP Packet Loss - Effect of TCP Traffic}
\cfoot{\hfill \thepage\ sur \pageref{LastPage}}

\title{Characteristics of UDP Packet Loss \\Effect of TCP Traffic\\~\\ 
\normalsize \texttt{https://www.isoc.org/inet97/proceedings/F3/F3\_1.HTM\\~}}

\author{%
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\begin{tabular}[t]{c}
Hidenari, Sawashima\\ \texttt{<hidena-s@is.aist-nara.ac.jp>}\\ Nara Institute of Science and Technology\\ Japan
\end{tabular} &
\begin{tabular}[t]{c}
Yoshiaki, Hori\\ \texttt{<hori@kyushu-id.ac.jp>} \\ Kyushu Institute of Design\\ Japan
\end{tabular} \\ \addlinespace[4ex] % create some vertical separation
\begin{tabular}[t]{c}
Hideki Sunahara\\ \texttt{<suna@wide.ad.jp>}\\ Nara Institute of Science and Technology\\ Japan
\end{tabular} &
\begin{tabular}[t]{c}
Yuji Oie\\ \texttt{<oie@itc.aist-nara.ac.jp>}\\ Nara Institute of Science and Technology\\ Japan
\end{tabular}
\end{tabular}
}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution and the explanation, that work perfectly :)